# Django save to DB: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-orm

I have a problem in def that save data into database.

```
    @staticmethod
    def _save(account, proxy,
              proxy_provider_id, period,
              country, start_date,
              price, meta,
              account_type, ip):
        try:
            period = int(period)
            end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=period)
            prx = Proxy()
            prx.account = account
            prx.proxy = proxy
            prx.proxy_provider_id = proxy_provider_id
            prx.period = period,
            prx.country = country,
            prx.start_date = start_date
            prx.end_date = end_date
            prx.price = price
            prx.meta = meta
            prx.ip = ip
            print('\n')
            print('Save proxy {}'.format(prx))
            print('account: {} type {}'.format(account, type(account)))
            print('proxy: {} type {}'.format(proxy, type(proxy)))
            print('proxy id: {} type {}'.format(proxy_provider_id, type(proxy_provider_id)))
            print('country: {} type {}'.format(country, type(country)))
            print('start date: {} type {}'.format(start_date, type(start_date)))
            print('end date: {} type {}'.format(end_date, type(end_date)))
            print('price: {} type {}'.format(price, type(price)))
            print('meta: {} type {}'.format(meta, type(meta)))
            print('ip: {} type {}'.format(ip, type(ip)))
            print('\n')
            prx.save() # exception raised there 

            payment = [start_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'),
                       end_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")]
            payments = json.loads(account.history_of_payments)
            payments.append(payment)
            account.history_of_payments = json.dumps(payments)
            account.account_type = account_type

            print('\n')
            print('Save account {}'.format(prx))
            print('payment: {} type {}'.format(payments, type(payments)))
            print('account type: {} type {}'.format(account_type, type(account_type)))
            print('\n')

            account.save(update_fields=['history_of_payments', 'account_type'])
            log.debug('Update account {}'.format(account))
        except Exception:
            raise ProxyException('Exception, when trying to save proxy {} {} for {} '
                                 'date {} price {} meta {} '
                                 .format(proxy, country, account.username,
                                         start_date, price, meta))
        else:
            log.info('Save new proxy {} {} for {} from {} to {} price {} meta {} '
                     .format(proxy, country, account.username,
                             start_date, end_date, price, meta))
            return True
```

I don't know, what cause this exception, because I don't try to save any tuple. You can check log. There are only srting, float, object, datetime and int types.

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Full log is:

```
Save proxy Proxy object
account: InstagramAccount object type <class 'models.models.InstagramAccount'>
proxy: jFdDVV:BxorDV@107.191.105.212:17160 type <class 'str'>
proxy id: 762064 type <class 'int'>
country: us type <class 'str'>
start date: 2017-05-26 16:09:31.604467+00:00 type <class 'datetime.datetime'>
end date: 2017-05-29 16:09:31.604467+00:00 type <class 'datetime.datetime'>
price: 3.6 type <class 'float'>
meta: {"2017/05/26": {"time": "16:09:13", "proxy_type": "http", "account_type": "trial", "country": "us", "proxy": "jFdDVV:BxorDV@107.191.105.212:17160", "price": 3.6, "currency": "RUB"}} type <class 'str'>
ip: 109.86.13.23 type <class 'str'>


[2017-05-26 16:09:31,604] DEBUG Proxy jFdDVV:BxorDV@107.191.105.212:17160 check is successful
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/instafy_py/src/service/views.py", line 130, in create_instagram_account
    username=username)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 385, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
models.models.DoesNotExist: InstagramAccount matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/instafy_py/src/proxy/manager.py", line 208, in _save
    prx.save()
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1045, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1053, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1006, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1006, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 945, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 755, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 747, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1832, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/instafy_py/src/service/views.py", line 169, in create_instagram_account
    3, 'trial')
  File "/usr/instafy_py/src/proxy/manager.py", line 156, in buy
    account_type, ip)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/src/proxy/manager.py", line 229, in _save
    start_date, price, meta))
proxy.manager.ProxyException: Exception, when trying to save proxy jFdDVV:BxorDV@107.191.105.212:17160 us for guv.vop date 2017-05-26 16:09:31.604467+00:00 price 3.6 meta {"2017/05/26": {"time": "16:09:13", "proxy_type": "http", "account_type": "trial", "country": "us", "proxy": "jFdDVV:BxorDV@107.191.105.212:17160", "price": 3.6, "currency": "RUB"}} 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 980, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 830, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 567, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 330, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 882, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/src/middlewares/startup_middleware.py", line 13, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/.virtualenvs/instafy_py/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/instafy_py/src/service/views.py", line 171, in create_instagram_account
    log.exception('Something wrong with proxy', e)
Message: 'Something wrong with proxy'
Arguments: (ProxyException('Exception, when trying to save proxy jFdDVV:BxorDV@107.191.105.212:17160 us for guv.vop date 2017-05-26 16:09:31.604467+00:00 price 3.6 meta {"2017/05/26": {"time": "16:09:13", "proxy_type": "http", "account_type": "trial", "country": "us", "proxy": "jFdDVV:BxorDV@107.191.105.212:17160", "price": 3.6, "currency": "RUB"}} ',),)
```

All data types are match with model

```
class InstagramAccount(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=45, primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    account_id_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='account_id_account')
    expired_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    history_of_payments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    account_type = models.TextField(default='trial')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'instagram_account'
        unique_together = (('account_id_account', 'username'),)

class Proxy(models.Model):
    id_proxy = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    proxy = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False, null=False)
    meta = models.TextField(null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False)
    period = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), ])
    # It can confuse, but our proxy provider have it own id for proxy
    proxy_provider_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False, blank=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey(InstagramAccount, models.DO_NOTHING,
                                db_column='instagram_account_account_id_account')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'proxy'
        unique_together = (('id_proxy', 'account'),)
```

if I use raw SQL query, it would be better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a comma at the end of the line where you set `prx.country`, which turns it into a tuple.

There are quite a few strange things in this code. Most importantly, you really should not catch all exceptions only to raise your own; you should catch the errors you know you can handle (and actually handle them, not raise another error); everything else you should let Django handle itself.

Comment: same sh...t, simple typo and look for a problem for 2 hours...